# Intuitive method for users to select either of 2 destinations in a search results interface

Tags: navigation, search-results

I am trying to design an interface where users navigate to modules (from a list of 2 or 3 modules) from a search results page.

**Notes:**

1. Every user will have a default module: example ModX
2. Every user will have more than 1 module: example ModX (default) & ModY & ModZ
3. Each module talks about CUSTOMERS or ACCOUNTs.
4. Each module is a menu item

**Problem**
Upon searching for a Customer name... example Disney Limited, the user will see "disney limited" in search results. The user should now be able to navigate to ModX by default, but in case he wishes to navigate to ModY of Disney Limited... how would he do it?

Comment: Hi Arun. Do you have a visual representation of this problem? Not sure I fully understand what a 'module' is from a UI perspective. Is a module a property of each individual search result? Can you also please expand on the part with 'each module is a menu item'. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Search answers could be something like the image attached. 
Where searching "masina" ( romanian for machine ) generates results in 3 categories.

[image]